# Sort array of 3 values, break up into three separate fields

Tags: javascript, arrays

Firstly, I'm self taught at programming so I apologize for any lack of basic knowledge I may possess about javascript.

I'm trying to collate an array out of many multiple check boxes which have been set as either "off" or outputting a 5 digit value in adobe acrobat for a PDF form. I can get the array formed. I cannot figure out how to take the array and have it select one of the array values and display just that one value on a distinct field.

What I'm looking to do is have the array display it's three values which have been collated from around 20+ different check boxes that could be checked into three separate fields.

Basically, a check box is a type of surgery which then corresponds to a particular billing code (5 digits) that I want to program to have displayed on separate lines which I will then pair with a diagnosis of disease code. I am not able to figure out how to split up the values from the array.

ex:

```
var aFieldNames = new Array("ORIF Patella","TKA","ACL Repair");

var cSurgery = "";

var aSxCode = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < aFieldNames.length; i++) {

cSurgery = this.getField(aFieldNames[i]).value;

if(cSurgery != "Off") {
aSxCode[aSxCode.length] = cSurgery;
}
```

I left out the incredibly long list of other check boxes and used only three in the example. This gets the array set up but I have no idea how to go about starting to sort the values into separate variables to be displayed. I'm not planning on more than three check boxes ever being checked at one time so am not bothering to code in a restriction to only three values.

Thanks for any help and guidance you can give me.

Comment: can you please create a js fiddle for the same.

Comment: Would saving the field name along with the surgery code be helpful? You can store an object in your aSxCode array instead of a list of just strings: `aSxCode.push({name: aFieldNames[i], surgery: cSurgery})` then later on when displaying you can lookup by fieldname and display the surgery code?

Comment: Side note: `aSxCode.push(cSurgery);` is more _intuitive_ than `aSxCode[aSxCode.length] = cSurgery;`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Jblackmer/cne1csg3/

Comment: Being self-taught, I don't know the specific Java language Adobe is using in the JSFiddle selection.

Comment: I read your question a few times, still having some trouble figuring out what your problem is -- are you having trouble tying data in the aSxCode array back to the field associated to it?

Comment: I want the three values associated with aSxCode to be split up from the array into separate variables, (ex: a, b, c) then I want to display one of the values into the field (ex: a) then I plan to copy/paste the written code into the next display field and display the next variable (ex: b). The reason I'm using this method is that there are more than 20+ field names I will have to watch and I feel it's easier to have the fields collate the checked boxes into a array then disperse the values from the array to each separate field.